# How to fix html error code in VsCode that says Enotdir: not a directory, stat?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I am very new to web development and I am starting my first project using frontendmentor.io. I began my project Monday and everything was working fine. All of a sudden on Tuesday, I began to get a error message when trying to open live server.

The error message reads:
`Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, stat '/Users/username/html/index.html/'`

I have searched plenty of forums and cannot really find anything that fits my situation. I am using only HTML and CSS for this project. I uninstalled VSCode and I lost all of my previous work, so I only have the code that frontendmentor provided to get started, but I can post that below if needed. I am sure I did something wrong, I just cannot figure out what exactly.

Comment: This happens to me when I'm not `cd`'d into the right directory. Could you post a screenshot of the window with the terminal in it too? thanks

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], and the FAQ [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem too.
I opened the CSS file with live server instead of `index.html` file and it works.

Answer (score 0):

it is actually super simple. Just go to extensions setting and find (should be second line) LIVE SERVER > SETTINGS > CUSTOM BROWSER in there you will find NULL ... so just change it to your browser. And it should be fine again.[Screenshot of extension settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8bVx.png)